# EventHandler into EventHandler

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I wan to call ContextMenu into EventHandler. THis code successfully works but I faced one issue.

```
bp.setOnContextMenuRequested(new EventHandler<ContextMenuEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ContextMenuEvent event)
            {

                ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("About");
                item1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("About");
                    }
                });
                MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("Preferences");
                item2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Preferences");
                    }
                });
                MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem("Close");
                item3.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
                    {

                    }
                });
                contextMenu.getItems().addAll(item1, item2, item3);

                bp.setOnContextMenuRequested(new EventHandler<ContextMenuEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ContextMenuEvent event)
                    {
                        contextMenu.show(bp, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
                        event.consume();
                    }
                });

                bp.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event)
                    {
                        contextMenu.hide();
                    }
                });
                event.consume();
            }
        });
```

When I load Tab content with this event handler I have to click twice the first time in order to call the context menu. I suppose that the reason if this is the EventHandler into EventHandler. How I can edit the code so I can call the Context menu with one EventHandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
bp.setOnContextMenuRequested(new EventHandler<ContextMenuEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ContextMenuEvent event)
            {

                ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("About");
                item1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("About");
                    }
                });
                MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("Preferences");
                item2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Preferences");
                    }
                });
                MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem("Close");
                item3.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
                    {

                    }
                });
                contextMenu.getItems().addAll(item1, item2, item3);

                contextMenu.show(bp, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());

                bp.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event)
                    {
                        contextMenu.hide();
                    }
                });
                event.consume();
            }
        });
```